# display an array of strings using select-element and ui-select

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to detemine the best way to display an array of string using the select-element and the ui-select. The html look like this.

```
        <div class="groupDisplay impersonate-role content" display: block id={{group.groupName}} ng-repeat="group in imp.groups track by group.groupName">
            <div id="apps-edit-close-but" class="edit-close-but" ng-click="removeImpersonateGroup(group)" style="right:16px; vertical-align: middle; search-div "></div>
            <div class="section-element">
                <div class="content-subtitle-dark" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Help Desk Role
                    <ui-select ng-model="group.selectedHelpdeskRole" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" style="width:500px">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Find Role">{{group.selectedHelpdeskRole}}</ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="role in group.availableHelpdeskRoles | roleBoxFilter: {value: $select.search}">
                          <div ng-bind-html="role | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                        </ui-select-choices>
                    </ui-select>
                </div>
            </div><br>

            <div class="section-element">
                <div class="content-subtitle-dark" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Roles to Impersonate
                    <ui-select multiple ng-model="group.selectedUserRoles" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" style="width:500px">
                        <ui-select-match placeholder="Find Role">{{group.selectedUserRoles}}</ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="roles in group.availableUserRoles | roleBoxFilter: {value: $select.search}">
                            <div ng-bind-html="roles | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                        </ui-select-choices>
                    </ui-select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the group.selectedUserRoles contains the array of strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I do what I have posted I get one uiselect with the single item on the second one I get an array of string like ["test","test2","test3"]

I would like to break up each member on the array into its own object to be displayed.